# Converting Java code to JS (jsweet error)

Tags: javascript, java

I wrote a code in Java which gets number of each piece type and fills some area with tetris block and print filled array.
I wanted to make website (probably on github.io, no server) which calculates this and print for other users.
I wrote the code in Eclipse(jdk 12.0.2) and no error on it.
But when I convert code with JSweet, it gave me some errors:

1.

```
final EnumMap<P,Integer> M = new EnumMap<>(P.class);
->type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Enum<P>'
```

2.

```
EnumMap<P,Integer> M = (something);
Iterator<Piece> P = new ArrayList<>(M.keySet().iterator());
->property 'slice' does not exist on type 'Set<P>'
```

Then I found GWT, but it seems like wont work without server... I tried it but it failed.
How to fix errors on JSweet? Or is there other apps to convert Java code to js?

(This is my first project in Java and Eclipse, and newbie in js)

Comment: It appears to be that an automatic tool has bugs. It happens. Though you can work around these bugs by adjusting the generated code manually. Doesn't seem impossible given these snippets, the fix is somewhat clear.

Comment: GWT does work without a server.
Just remove the server part and web.xml.

I think this code works just fine in GWT.